# tr:hover & tr:nth-child(odd ~ even) does not work together

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wanted to highlight the table row on hover. So I've used the following CSS rule,

```
.my-table tbody tr:hover{
  background-color: #BFC0C2;
}
```

It worked well alone. Later I've included the CSS rule to make the different background color for odd and even rows of the table,

```
.my-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.my-table tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background: #f2f2f3;
}
```

Now the odd and even rows are having differnt background color But on hover the row is not getting highlighted. Can't I use both of them together? [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/g6mDm8L3pN6J5OFILXfB?p=preview) is the plunker.

Comment: That said, off hand, it looks like a specificity weight issue.

Comment: Probably the hover is getting override by the rules applyed to the nth-child selector. Try to put it after them.

Comment: As @Paulie_D points it's specificity ... both selectors has the same level of specificity but since the nth-childs are declared last takes precedence ... https://plnkr.co/edit/lZWH7ir1ZaL3QWu9kB4T?p=preview

Comment: Just move the `.my-table tbody tr:hover` rule to come after the nth-child rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a specificity / cascade issue.

Either re-order the CSS

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FF0000;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}
.table tbody tr:hover {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OR** increase the specifity of the hover in the same way

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(n):hover {
  background-color: #BFC0C2;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FF0000;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Setting both the odd and even children seems redundant. Just give the `tr` a default background colour and override it for odd *or* even children (not both)

Answer (score 2):

You can also change td's background

```
  .my-table tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #BFC0C2;
  }
  .my-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .my-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f2f2f3;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

its just the matter of specificity of the selector, increase it my any mean will solve the problem example

```
.my-table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #BFC0C2 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examining in the browser you can see that both selectors apply, but one is overridden:

[image]

Just place it earlier in code or add `!important` and it'll work fine.